# When loading product by id how to handle invalid product id error

Tags: product

What is the best way to check whether product id is incorrect/not available?

Currently I'm doing it this way,

```
$product       = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$productIdMage = $product->getId();
if ( !isset($productIdMage) || $productIdMage == "" ) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('This Product is not available.'); 
    $this->_clearShopingCart();             
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    $errorStatus = false;
}
```

Comment: you are doing for single product or multiple product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per as magento,if a model *`Mage::getModel('ModelPreFixIdentie/Modelname')`* is loaded by **load()**  then it **`db existence is checked by getId()`**.

And the  `getId()` given **false** value whenever the **record is not exit at db** .

> ```
> $object=Mage::getModel('ModelPreFixIdentie/Modelname')->load($id);
>
> if(!$object->getId()):
> // record does not exit in system
> endif;
> ```

You need to check **product by getId()**.If the product is  not available for that particular id's product then ***getId()*** return ***false value***.

**Just change**

```
.....
$productIdMage = $product->getId();
if ( !isset($productIdMage) || $productIdMage == "" ) {
....
```

**to**

```
.......
//$product->getId();
if ($product->getId()) {
....
```

Answer (score 0):

in your case, you have to check directly.

```
$product       = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$productIdMage = $product->getId();
//Because $product->getId() returns boolean.
if ($productIdMage) {
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('This Product is not available.'); 
    $this->_clearShopingCart();             
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    $errorStatus = false;
}
```